# Converting Spring Dispatcher Servlet path to ZuulServlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

While uploading large files using Zuul Proxy -
To bypass the Spring DispatcherServlet I changed the URL:
From: http://localhost:8081/MyService/file
To: http://localhost:8081/zuul/MyService/file

Preserved disabling of Spring multipart upload:

```
spring:
    http:
        multipart:
            enabled: false
```

But I don't want to use any extra prefix (/zuul/) to my client URI(host/MyService/**), so in my pre filter I am checking if the original request is multipart-form or not?

And if the request is multipart-form, I am trying to update my request URI to host/zuul/MyService. Also I want to set the boolean isDispatcherServletRequest to false.

Here is my pre filter -

```
@Override
    public Object run() throws ZuulException {



        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
        System.out.println("Request type of content type "+request.getContentType());
        String requestType = request.getContentType();
        if(requestType.contains("multipart/form-data")) {

            String originalRequestPath = request.getRequestURI();
            String modifiedRequestPath = "/zuul" + originalRequestPath;
            ctx.put("REQUEST_URI_KEY", modifiedRequestPath);



        }
        return null;
    }
```

Question 1 : How do I put the new URI to requestContext?

Question 2 : How do I disable the DispatcherServletRequest in filter?